# No sound on a realtek AC97

Tags: 10.10, sound, realtek

I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 and I've no sound. I tried few method suggested in ubuntu forums like reinstall alsa but nothing works? My PC is old and my audio card is Realtek's AC'97. Any suggestions how can I resolve this problem?

**Update**

Actually my audio card died after installing Ubuntu, so when I'm backed to Win it still not worked.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking to make sure nothing was muted. In the terminal, type alsaplayer.

Is your volume turned up, or is the speaker muted?
Double click on the "speaker" icon in the upper right hand corner of the screen. This will launch the Volume Control application, which has various sliders to control the volume. Make sure that the speaker, headphone and master sliders are not muted, and have the volume up from zero. On a fresh install of Ubuntu 8.10, the Speaker volume is turned all the way down.

You can launch Gnome Volume Control application using Alt+ and type

gnome-volume-control

Comment: Nothing of this helped, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Take linux driver 2.6 click on global

Install the pulse audio driver and set hdmi out as fall-back in the output device, same for finding the correct input-source-device like a webcam-microphone.

VLC-mediaplayer in simple-preferences to alsa-output, correct hdmi with software-conversions and audio, audio-device same.

Comment: Same as in Lubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0):

I expierienced the same, building a new PC with older hardware (AC97 onboard sound). I found out that two jumpers were missing on the mainboard since no AC97 front connector from the case was connected. With the jumpers missing the mainboard "thinks" the sound is routed to the headphone jack, so no sound is routed to the back panel jack.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_High_Definition_Audio

"In the AC'97 design, the audio output is sent to the jack. If the headphones are not plugged in, the jack directs the audio to the return pins that are connected to the speakers. When a headphone is plugged into the front panel jack, the audio signal goes to the headphones; the return pins are disconnected, so no audio signal goes to the speakers. Many motherboards with AC'97 audio need two jumpers to short the pins in case no front panel audio module is connected."

...old thread but I believe this may help a few others dealing with older hardware.