# Intel AC'97 Sound Problem

Tags: sound, alsa

I just installed ubuntu 11 and my sound isn't working. More specifically if the sound is all the way up I can hear very faint noises.

I've read around and this seems to be a common problem historically, but none of the fixes are working for me. There appears to be a similar question already out there [No sound on a realtek AC97](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33190/no-sound-on-a-realtek-ac97)

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ICH5 [Intel ICH5], device 0: Intel ICH [Intel ICH5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ICH5 [Intel ICH5], device 4: Intel ICH - IEC958 [Intel ICH5 - IEC958]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


$ lspci | grep audio

00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
```

I've ensured that my volume is up in alsamixer from this [thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/sound-problems-intel-corp-82801eb-er-ich5-ich5r-ac97-audio-controller-rev-02-a-270323/)

I've also tried [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=14989&highlight=ac97_quirk&page=2) fix from the guide, with no luck.

I've tried to update to the newest alsa drivers, but also no luck. [This](http://tehpost.blogspot.com/2008/07/ubuntu-no-sound-using-intel-corporation.html) post from 2007 even suggested downgrading to a different kernel rev. I am tempted to try it, but there has got to be a better way.

Please let me know if there is anymore information that I provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the easiest solution to my problem was to buy a new audio card for $20. Now the sound works great! My conjecture is that the mother board sound was dead, even though I was hearing a very faint "Front Center" via aplay.

Comment: was it a video card or audio card that you replaced?

Comment: good catch it was an audio card.

Answer (score 0):

I also made it to let my sound card work properly under Debian 6.0 (squeeze) and 7.0 (wheezy). My hardware is DELL Precision 470 Workstation and i found my sound card keywords are: "intel" "82801EB" "ac97".

I could not remember exactly what I did exactly, but the following info definitely helped:

- lost sound with 11.10 - [Lost sound with 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103269/lost-sound-with-11-10)
- have problem with my ac97 ... - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1841634&s=c09ec066e5e07fbe674e74f0bdb59b22
- download driver (**for both Win and Linux**) from [Realtek Sound Driver Download Page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=8&PFid=14&Level=3&Conn=2)

I do remember that **pulseaudio package alone** can make my sound card work on both debian 6.0 & 7.0.