# Lost sound with 11.10

Tags: sound, soundcard

I installed Ubuntu some days ago. The sound worked perfectly, but today there was a shortcircuit and I lost the sound. I thought it was the sound card, but I started Windows XP and it worked fine. What should I do?

My sound card is an **Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) AC'97**.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried unmuting? I sometimes experience that the sound is disabled when I improperly shutdown (e.g. `kill` or hard power off) at next boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translated message:

Well maybe it's a driver or a problem with PulseAudio. Make sure the package *pulseaudio* is installed.

---

Original:

Pues quizás se trate de algún driver o algún problema con PulseAudio :|
Comprueba que el paquete "pulseaudio" esté instalado :P

Comment: Pulseaudio no estaba instalado :P

Comment: Como antes me funcionaba... Bueno, voy a revisarlo, gracias :)

Comment: Pues instalalo y me cuentas, de nada ;)

Comment: Rsuelto... Aunque, por un error no relacionado, tuve que reinstalar Ubuntu :P

Comment: Genial, aunque siento que hayas tenido que reinstalar :/